# Can't ping or ssh my VM in openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openvswitch

I have a three node installation of openstack, everything works fine before. But now i can't ping or ssh the instances in openstack.

I can ping the ip of the controler and the networker, also from my controller i can see that all nova agents are up and the same thing for neutron-agents

I can ping the gateway to the external net from router namspace. I can also ping the subnet interface from router but i can't ping the instance using the floating ip adress

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Can you ping external network gateway from router name space? Can you ping internal ip of the instance from router name space?

Comment: Yes i can ping the public ip of my external gateway, and the internal ip from the namespace of the router

Comment: Please check the security group applied to the instance, is ssh access enabled ? what about ICMP rules? And check if you can ping outside from the instance (Checking if the snat working correctly)

Comment: The IcMP and the SSH protocol are allowed, it's weird coz i can access and ping some of my instances and not others

Comment: are all the problematic instances on a single host? are there any fine instances on the same host?

Comment: No, on the same compute we have instances that we can't access or ping and an instance that we can access

Comment: I would try to create a new instance on the same compute node and test if it works, Then I would rebuild the problematic instance.

Comment: I already tried that, and it doesn't work

Comment: Is this a production environment? if not I would restart nova-* and neutron-* services on controller, networking and compute nodes and try creating an instance.

Comment: I restarted the openvswitch agent on the compute node and it solves my problem. Thank you Farhad for your assistance

Comment: No problem, Just accept the answer in case we can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please restart Neutron services on controller, networking and Compute nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Farhad it solved my problem.

I followed this tutorial to restart the services. Must restart nova and neutron services on both controller and compute nodes.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/438871/how-to-restart-openstack-services-after-restart-logout/1341668#1341668